# finding red color words in docx file through python code

Tags: python, docx

I have a mircosoft docx file which has few words in red color.
Now I want to read that file through  python code and extract those red words.

But I cannot find the apis that should be used for it.. I tried to iterate on para to access individual words .. but it says para is not iterable .
I'am also not sure how to check color of the word.

Can you please help on it.

```
import docx

def readtxt(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        print(para.text);

readtxt('C:\\Users\\X\\some.docx')
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, the function will return a list of all contiguous parts of the document which are in `red`.

```
import docx
from docx.shared import RGBColor

def readtxt(filename):
    doc = docx.Document(filename)
    fullText = []
    for para in doc.paragraphs:
        for run in para.runs:
            if run.font.color.rgb == RGBColor(255, 000, 000):
                fullText.append(run.text)
    return fullText

fullText = readtxt('filepath.docx')
```

Also, please check that you're passing the `filepath` correctly.

Comment: Hi, When i use para.runs , i see that it is breaking even a single word into 2 in few cases.  I expected that it will give individual words with each run .. Is there something more that needs to be done ?

Comment: The above code would return a list of all the contiguous parts of the document which has a red color font formatting, please provide an example of what your document looks like, what words are causing the issue and what is your expected output

Comment: I got it for now . Thanks for your help !! Will open this question if required.